# Quelle est la nuance de sens entre les phrases de chaque paire ci-après

Tags: sens, participe-présent, gérondif

> A1 Connaissant vos devoirs, vous les remplirez.

> A2 En connaissant vos devoirs, vous les remplirez.

> B1 Sachant vos leçons, vous obtiendrez des éloges.

> B2 En sachant vos leçons, vous obtiendrez des éloges.

> C1 Vous comportant en honnête homme, vous serez estimé.

> C2 En vous comportant en honnête homme, vous serez estimé.

> D1 En entendant démarrer la basse, le batteur se mit en action.

> D2 Entendant démarrer la basse, le batteur se mit en action.

> E1 J’ai vexé Juliette en déclinant son invitation.

> E2 Déclinant son invitation, j’ai vexé Juliette.

> F1  Il a déclaré valider notre projet en soupirant.

> F2 Soupirant, il a déclaré valider notre projet.

> G1 En ayant travaillé de la sorte, vous méritez une augmentation.

> G2 Ayant travaillé de la sorte, vous méritez une augmentation.

> H1 En amusant son entourage, il s’était attiré beaucoup de sympathie.

> H2 Amusant son entourage, il s’était attiré beaucoup de sympathie.

> I1 En amusant la galerie, il ne cessait de répéter les mêmes blagues.

> I2 Amusant la galerie, il ne cessait de répéter les mêmes blagues.

> J1 En convainquant ses proches, il tapait du poing pour appuyer ses propos.

> J2 Convainquant ses proches, il tapait du poing pour appuyer ses propos.

Quelles seraient des astuces qui pourraient aider à distinguer les deux formes verbales, c’est-à-dire dans quels cas utiliser « en » (un gérondif) et dans quels cas non (un participe présent) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1/A2: ?
B1: Puisque vous savez vos leçons
B2: Si vous savez vos leçons
C1: Puisque vous vous comportez...
C2: Si vous vous comportez...
D1: Au moment où il a entendu la basse démarrer
D2: Parce qu'il a entendu la basse démarrer
E1: Car j'ai décliné son invitation
E2: Comme j'ai décliné son invitation
F1: Tout en soupirant
F2: Idem
G1: Parce que vous avez travaillé de la sorte
G2: Puisque vous avez travaillé de la sorte
H1: Parce qu'il
H2: Alors qu'il
I1: Pendant qu'il
I2: Ce qui amusait la galerie
J1: Pendant que...
J2: Idem

Comment: Je suppose qu’il est possible d’établir un parallèle entre A1, A2 et B1, B2, C1, C2. Personnellement, j’aurais interverti les propositions H1 et H2, ce qui fait que H2 aurait été en phase avec D2. Je n’arrive pas à percevoir la nuance qui existe entre E1 et E2. G1 ne me convainc pas.

Comment: Et si, en J2, la proposition participiale et la principale avaient été interverties, au participe présent auriez-vous substitué la construction « ce qui convainquit ses proches »?

Comment: Ne pourrait-on pas aussi interpréter la participiale E1 comme une référence temporelle: j’ai vexé juliette quand j’ai décliné son invitation? À tout le moins, ce serait l’interprétation naturelle qui me viendrait à l’esprit si j’intervertissais la proposition principale avec la proposition participiale, c-à-d « En déclinant son invitation, j’ai vexé Juliette » implique bien si je m’en rapporte à mes connaissances actuelles « Quand j’ai décliné son invitation, j’ai vexé Juliette, n’est-ce pas?

Comment: Je me demande quel est le processus qui intervient dans le cerveau derrière ces interprétations différentes de la participiale en fonction de sa position dans une phrase.

Comment: « Tout en » ne précise aucune fonction circonstancielle ; c'est une forme d'insistance :  https://www.slps.org/cms/lib/MO01001157/Centricity/Domain/5853/Le%20participe.pdf.

Comment: N’existe-t-il donc pas d’astuces autres que s’en remettre à son instinct (ou à quelques indications élémentaires) pour donner un sens à une phrase qui comporte une proposition participiale?

Comment: Il n’y a donc pas de méthode systématique fiable qui permet d’interpréter de manière absolue et sans équivoque une participiale?

Comment: Je t'ai donné mon ressenti pour chacune des phrases. Je ne cherche pas à convaincre, tout le monde n'est pas forcé d'avoir le même avis. Non, il n'existe pas de méthode systématique qui permette d'interpréter à 100 % le sens attendu de ces phrase. Le contexte, le ton (absent à l'écrit) pourront faire privilégier un sens ou un autre. Je maintiens ma compréhension de H1 et H2 mais il n'y a pas une grande distance entre les deux. Il n'y a pas de grande nuance non plus entre E1 et E2, c'est bien le fait d'avoir décliné l'invitation qui a vexé Juliette. Idem pour G1 et G2.

Comment: @Antivlad Il ne s'agit aucunement d'instinct mais de savoir ; il n'y a pas d'autre option d'acquisition de ce savoir que la formation par le biais de l'exemple à partir d'une lecture assidue de bons auteurs ; ultimement, le résultat de ce savoir, comme il a atteint un degré assez élevé, est la possibilité de déterminer son explication, son fondement,  que les grammairiens découvrent plus tôt et en un approfondissement bien plus grand parce que leur lectures auront été secondées par la recherche, par un vocabulaire qui leur permet de penser, celui de la linguistique.

Answer (score 0):

**I**

Pour répondre à cette question, commençons par les déductions suivantes qui résulte d'une synthèse de Estelle Moline dans son article, [Peut-on parler de « valeurs sémantiques » du gérondif ?](https://books.openedition.org/apu/7431),  Artois Presses Université, 2011.

> […] le gérondif ne possède aucune valeur sémantique spécifique :
>
> > On dit souvent [...] que le gérondif marque ici le temps, là la cause ailleurs encore l’opposition ou la condition, tout cela sans changer de forme. Cela prouve donc que le gérondif ne suffit pas à indiquer ces différentes valeurs et donc qu’il n’en indique en soi aucune. C’est le contexte, la situation qui font établir entre les faits une relation logique qui n’est pas exprimée grammaticalement. (Grevisse, 1986 : 1648)
> > Le gérondif en soi, qui garde toujours la même forme [en V-ant] est non marqué quant aux effets de sens, même s’il est clair [...] qu’il en favorise certains et qu’il en bloque d’autres. (Halmøy, 2003 : 87)
> > Le lien de subordination non-complétive gérondive [doit être considéré] comme un moule syntaxique, vide, où des concepts sont coulés. Contrairement à ce que cette analogie peut amener à penser, ces concepts ne sont pas une matière informe, mais ils sont structurés par des relations logiques fondamentales et indépendantes de la langue. (Fasciolo, 2007 : 128)
>
> En d’autres termes, la présence d’un gérondif n’indique rien d’autre que le fait qu’une relation doit être établie entre les deux procès décrits, Vger étant « subordonné » à Vconj (cf. Halmøy, 2003 ; Kleiber, 2006, 2007a et b ; Fasciolo, 2007). Comme le souligne Halmøy (2003), l’interprétation de cette relation repose sur des paramètres divers :
>
> > C’est le rapprochement du sémantisme des deux verbes en jeu et de leurs expansions qui permet d’envisager un certain éventail d’effets de sens, l’interprétation de la relation ne pouvant se faire qu’a posteriori. D’autres éléments du contexte linguistique et situationnel (ou pragmatique) peuvent contribuer à l’interprétation du sémantisme de la construction (ibid. : 88).
>
> 12 Il existe certes quelques indices linguistiques permettant de guider l’interprétation de la relation entre Vger et Vconj (cf. infra, 2.2. et 3.), mais celle-ci repose pour l’essentiel sur des facteurs extralinguistiques, en l’occurrence la mise en relation du contenu sémantique des prédicats utilisés avec les connaissances que nous avons du monde dans lequel nous vivons (cf. Kleiber, 2006 : 128-129). Dans cette optique, les relations temporelles entre Vger et Vconj ne seront pas considérées comme étant premières, mais au contraire comme étant établies par défaut, quand aucune autre relation ne peut être instaurée entre les deux procès : la mise en relation temporelle correspond en effet à la relation minimale qui peut être effectuée entre deux procès.

<sup>*</sup>   <sub>Vger :  le prédicat au gérondif

   Vconj :  le prédicat à temps fini [c'est à dire une proposition introduite par une conjonction]</sub>

On peut ajouter que s'il en est ainsi pour le gérondif, c'est à plus forte raison le cas pour le participe présent, puisqu'il a la même construction simplifiée par l'absence de « en ».

**Rappel** Les notions suivantes peuvent être exprimées par le participe présent et le gérondif.

**participe présent** : le temps, la cause, la condition, la concession, conséquence/résultat

**gérondif** : le temps, la simultanéité, la cause, la condition, la manière, l'opposition/la concession

**II**

*Réponse à la première question seulement (A1/A2)*

> A1 Connaissant vos devoirs, vous les remplirez.
> A2 En connaissant vos devoirs, vous les remplirez.

Il n'y a pas assez de contexte dans ces phrases pour essayer d'associer aux formes non finies une notion circonstancielle unique. Il existe au moins  deux choix possibles de valeur circonstancielle pour A1 ; il est nécessaire de construire au moins un contexte correspondant à chacune.

*contexte 1*  Évidemment, si vous ne savez pas trop bien quelles sont vos responsabilités, vous n'avez pas tous les moyens vous permettant d'agir convenablement, alors que connaissant vos devoirs, vous les remplirez. (*condition : « alors que si vous connaissez… »*)

*contexte 2* Tout vous a été expliqué, il ne vous manque rien ; connaissant vos devoirs, vous les remplirez. (*cause : « comme » causal, « comme vous connaissez (maintenant) vos devoirs… »*)

Le contexte portant sur la condition peut être exprimé aussi bien avec le gérondif (« en connaissant »). Il y a donc une équivalence de A1 et A2 sur le plan de la condition. Cependant, sur le plan de la cause (second contexte) il ne semble pas y avoir d'équivalence. Une analyse détaillé m'échappe complètement, mais dans un effort minimum d'explication, il ne faut pas ignorer cette constatation relevée dans [Peut-on parler de « valeurs sémantiques » du gérondif ?](https://books.openedition.org/apu/7521?lang=fr) d'Estelle Moline :

> « Le gérondif ne favorise d’ailleurs pas particulièrement l’inférence causale. ».

Il n'existe pas d'« astuces » pour différencier ces formes, et dans la limites, les concepts connues ne sont que de peu de secours à cet effet. L'assurance de rester dans les normes n'est apportée que par une utilisation scrupuleuse des modèles connus que l'on a bien assimilés et d'éviter les possibilités douteuse en se rabattant sur d'autres moyens.